# Magento Save And Next

Tags: php, forms, magento, button

For my company I'm working on a custom translation module for Magento.
On the form for translating an existing string, I would like to change the behaviour of the "Save And Continue"-button to  a "Save And Next"-button.
With which I mean that instead of still editing thesame string, you get the next one in line.

I have tried to edit the link that is called for the Save And Continue:

```
Original:
[save-link] + "/back/edit/"

To:
[save-link] + "/back/edit/id/[id]/"
```

But to no avail. I'm hoping someone can set me in the right direction.

The unchanged code of the edit-form:

```
<?php

class Phpro_Advancedtranslate_Block_Adminhtml_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_objectId = 'id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'advancedtranslate';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml';

        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('advancedtranslate')->__('Save Item'));
        $this->_updateButton('delete', 'label', Mage::helper('advancedtranslate')->__('Delete Item'));

        $this->_addButton('saveandcontinue', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Save And Next'),
            'onclick'   => 'saveAndContinueEdit()',
            'class'     => 'save',
        ), -100);

        $currentId = Mage::getSIngleton('adminhtml/session')->getTranslateId();
        $strings = Mage::getModel("advancedtranslate/advancedtranslate")->getCollection();
        foreach ($strings as $string) {
            $id = $string->getId();

            if ($id != $currentId && $id < $nextId) {
                $nextId = $id;
            }
        }

        $this->_formScripts[] = "
            function toggleEditor() {
                if (tinyMCE.getInstanceById('advancedtranslate_content') == null) {
                    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'advancedtranslate_content');
                } else {
                    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'advancedtranslate_content');
                }
            }

            function saveAndContinueEdit(){
                editForm.submit($('edit_form').action+'back/edit/');
            }
        ";
    }

    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        return Mage::helper('advancedtranslate')->__("Edit Item '%s'", 'test');

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality has to happen in the controller that handles the Post. Set the _redirect  to redirect to the next item.